# Using accordions in tabs with visual composer in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I'm using the biss theme within Wordpress to create my site. One of the pages has "tabs' element on the Visual Composer front-end editor. However, I want to insert accordions in one of the tabs.

Apparently this function isn't allowed in Visual Composer(dragging the tabs element within another tabs element).I have tried to use raw html,css and javacript but there seem to be an issue. can anyone help me with a solution.

Comment: This is the creator's explanation: "WordPress shortcodes have restrictions for element nesting, also very very complex layouts are not according to good practices of usability too."

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Composer is very tricky. Not recommended if you are not savvy web programmer. Relevant plugins are getting complicated as time goes. You can not helping out giving up wordpress. So recommend use default plain theme without any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

you can choose "Backend Editor" from visual composer then you can add the accordion code manually in the tabs

```
[brs_tabs]
[vc_accordion][/vc_accordion]
[/brs_tabs]
```